# How to get text from JTextField, convert to a string, and use this string in a different java public class

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield

I have a GUI that has 2 JTextFields- `EmailLoginField` and `jPasswordField1`. Ill just discuss the `EmailLoginField` and just duplicate what is recommended on `jPasswordField1` too.

So heres some GUI code:

```
package p;
imports ...

public class EmailLoginGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public EmailLoginGUI() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        ...
        EmailLoginField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    }

    ...

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    EmailMainGUI open = new EmailMainGUI();
    open.setVisible(true);
```

This next code snippet is what I have tried to do to get the text from the `JTextField EmailLoginField` in `EmailLoginGUI.java`

```
public String getEmailLoginField(){
    return EmailLoginField.getText();

}

public String getjPasswordField(){
    return jPasswordField1.getText();
}
```

Here is the next part (not assuming the code immediately above is correct). This next code is an entirely different public class, which same package of course. Here is what I have tried it should look at the EmailLoginGUI class and get the JTextField content, eventually storing it as a `String`.

PLEASE NOTE: the final strings that contain the JTextField content MUST NOT be inside the `SendEmail(EmailLoginGUI c1, EmailLoginGUI c2){`. They should be just outside of it just inside `public class SendEmail {` this is so that they can be used by other code later.

```
package p;
imports ...
public class SendEmail {


JTextField userTF;
    JPasswordField passPF;

        SendEmail(EmailLoginGUI c1, EmailLoginGUI c2){
        userTF.setText(c1.getEmailLoginField());
        passPF.setText(c2.getjPasswordField());

    }


    public String user(){
        return userTF.getText();
    }

    public String pass() {
        return passPF.getText();
    }

    ...

    SendEmail(...) {

    Properties props = new Properties();

            ...

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator()
    {

        protected javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
        {
            return new javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication(user(), pass()); //This is where the final strings need to go.
        }
});
```

Hopefully what I am trying to do is clear:
Get the content from JTextField created in `EmailLoginGUI.java`. Get this into `SendEmail.java`. Its final type should be `String` and is 'just on the inside' of the `public class SendEmail`. I have had everything from NullPointerException to Cannot find symbol for hours! Think I've been attempting it for so long that I could benefit from some fresh eyes!
Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you allready check, if a String is in your Textfield and you can read from there? Otherwise you have to check first, why you can not read the Textfield.

Comment: Don't use getText on a JPasswordField, this is security risk

Comment: So, conceptually, you want to present the user with your login view, a modal dialog would be easier, otherwise, you'll need some kind of observer/listener that the controller can register with your view and receive notifications. Once the view is filled out and the user clicks login, use the getters from your view to get the details and pass these to the other class

Comment: I realised both the security risk and how a dialogue would be easier, however I don't have time to go back to change it really. I have already coded the listener too so that's not a problem. But yes that's what I want to do! Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In SendEmail class create Constructor which has an argument of user input

```
SendEmail(String userInput) {
  //Your Code
}
```

In EmailLoginGUI create

```
String userInput = EmailLoginField.getText().toString(); 
SendEmail sendemail = new SendEmail(userInput);
```

This method works I have used it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

> I realised both the security risk and how a dialogue would be easier, however I don't have time to go back to change it really. I have already coded the listener too so that's not a problem. But yes that's what I want to do! Where am I going wrong?

Then you need to implement some kind of [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html).

Start by defining the expected operations that the login view might generate, for example, it's reasonable to expect that the user can either accept or cancel the view

```
public interface EmailLoginListener {
    public void emailLoginWasAccepted(EmailLoginGUI gui);
    public void emailLoginWasCanceled(EmailLoginGUI gui);
}
```

Update the view to provide support for the listener

```
public class EmailLoginGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private List<EmailLoginListener> listeners;

    public EmailLoginGUI() {
        initComponents();
        listeners = new ArrayList<>(25);
    }

    //...

    public void addEmailLoginListener(EmailLoginListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeEmailLoginListener(EmailLoginListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    protected void fireLoginWasAccepted() {
        for (EmailLoginListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.emailLoginWasAccepted(this);
        }
    }

    protected void fireLoginWasCanceled() {
        for (EmailLoginListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.emailLoginWasCanceled(this);
        }
    }
}
```

In your action handlers for your buttons on the `EmailLoginGUI` view, trigger the required event...

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    fireLoginWasAccepted();
}
```

Remember, you should also do this for the cancel operation if you have one.

Now, when you create an instance of `EmailLoginGUI`, make sure you also register a `EmailLoginListener` with it

```
EmailLoginGUI loginView = new EmailLoginGUI();
loginView.addEmailLoginListener(new EmailLoginListener() {
    @Override
    public void emailLoginWasAccepted(EmailLoginGUI gui) {
        gui.dispose();
        String email = gui.getEmailLoginField();
        String password = gui.getjPasswordField();

        EmailMainGUI open = new EmailMainGUI();
        open.setCredentials(email, password);
        //...
        open.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void emailLoginWasCanceled(EmailLoginGUI gui) {
        // Exit the program?
        gui.dispose();
    }
});
//...
loginView.setVisible(true);
```

This will require you to either change the constructor of `EmailMainGUI` to accept the email and password or a method to pass that information to the class (as I've demonstrated above)

Finally change `SendEmail` to accept `String` values instead of your gui components

```
public class SendEmail {

    String email;
    String password;

    SendEmail(String email, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String user() {
        return email;
    }

    public String pass() {
        return password;
    }
}
```